# avoid rebuilding node_modules in elastic beanstalk

Tags: node.js, git, amazon-web-services, npm, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We have a fairly simple node.js app, but due to AWS Elastic Beanstalk deployment mechanism, it takes about 5 minutes to roll-out a new version (via `git aws.push`) even after a single file commit.

I.e. the commit itself (and upload) is fast (only 1 file to push), but then Elastic Beanstalk fetches whole package from S3, unzips it and runs `npm install`, which causes node-gyp to compile some modules. Upon installation/building completion, Elastic Beanstalk wipes `/var/app/current` and replaces it with the new app version.

Needless to say, constant node_modules rebuilding is not necessary, and rebuilding that takes 30 seconds on my old Macbook Air, takes >5 mins on a ec2.micro instance, not fun.

I see two approaches here:

1. tweak `/opt/containerfiles/ebnode.py` and play with node_modules location to avoid its removal and rebuilding upon deployment.
2. set up a git repo on Elastic Beanstalk EC2 instance and basically re-write deployment procedure ourselves, so /var/app/current receives pushes and runs `npm install` only when necessary (which makes Elastic Beanstalk to look like OpsWorks..)

Both options lack grace and are prone to issues when Amazon updates their Elastic Beanstalk hooks and architecture.

Maybe somebody has a better idea how to avoid constant rebuilding of node_modules that are already present in the app dir? Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a better idea. I struggled with this, along with a list of other issues (no support for recent Node versions, non-deterministic deployment results), and in the end I went the self-managed EC2 route instead.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Are there any best practices on how to automate node.js deployment to EC2 via git hooks and such? What about automated scaling, monitoring and all that jazz that ELB boasts about?

Comment: As a note, Amazon Elastic Load Balancing (ELB) is different from AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I had to re-read this post a couple of times wondering why you were messing with the load balancer. :)

Comment: My bad, it's easy to get lost in AWS abbreviations :)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Thanks Kirill, it was really helpful !

I'm just sharing my config file for people who just look the simple solution to the `npm install`. This file needs to be placed in the `.ebextensions` folder of the project, it is lighter since it doesn't include last version of node installation, and ready to use.

It also dynamically checks the node version installed, so no need for it to be included in the env.vars file.

**`.ebextensions/00_deploy_npm.config`**

```
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/env.vars" :
    mode: "000775"
    owner: root
    group: users
    content: |
      export NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
      export NODE_PATH=`ls -td /opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-* | head -1`/bin
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/50npm.sh" :
    mode: "000775"
    owner: root
    group: users
    content: |
      #!/bin/bash
      . /opt/elasticbeanstalk/env.vars
      function error_exit
      {
        eventHelper.py --msg "$1" --severity ERROR
        exit $2
      }

      #install not-installed yet app node_modules
      if [ ! -d "/var/node_modules" ]; then
        mkdir /var/node_modules ;
      fi
      if [ -d /tmp/deployment/application ]; then
        ln -s /var/node_modules /tmp/deployment/application/
      fi

      OUT=$([ -d "/tmp/deployment/application" ] && cd /tmp/deployment/application && $NODE_PATH/npm install 2>&1) || error_exit "Failed to run npm install.  $OUT" $?
      echo $OUT
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/configdeploy/pre/50npm.sh" :
    mode: "000666"
    owner: root
    group: users
    content: |
       #no need to run npm install during configdeploy
```

Comment: thanks for your comment. Yes, I guess most people looking only to speed up npm rebuild times will benefit from your config. I'll make it a default answer, but in case someone would like a more sophisticated solution, please refer to my answer or better-faster-elastic-beanstalk repo: http://github.com/kopurando/better-faster-elastic-beanstalk

Comment: @Tronix117 Running this straight out of the box gives us `ERROR: Failed to run npm install.  /usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory` Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: @Mirage It seems that npm can not be launched, because node is not a know command on the system, seems to be a PATH issue. You can resolve it by changing `$NODE_PATH/npm install` to `$NODE_PATH/node $NODE_PATH/npm install` to force using the `node` binary within the `$NODE_PATH` to launch `npm`

Comment: I tried that, it gave a whole other set of permission denied errors (couldn't write to logs, did not have access to the NPM_TOKEN env var) and so on and so forth. Decided to skip the caching for now.

Comment: @mirage yes, you should have something wrong with your config. But actualy this script has been made 2 years ago, since then, AWS changed a few stuff. The idea is here, but it can need some tweaks for it to work nowadays.

Comment: For me, this failed with error `/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory`, I fixed it by adding `PATH="$PATH:$NODE_PATH"` on line 29, one line above `OUT=$(...)`.

Answer (score 38):

25/01/13 NOTE: updated scripts to run npm -g version upgrade (only once, on initial instance roll out or rebuild) and to avoid NPM operations during EB configuration change (when app dir is not present, to avoid error and to speed up configuration updates).

Okay, Elastic Beanstalk behaves dodgy with recent node.js builds (including presumably supported v.0.10.10), so I decided to go ahead and tweak EB to do the following:

1. to install ANY node.js version as per your env.config (including
   the most recent ones that are not yet supported by AWS EB)
2. to avoid rebuilding existing node modules, including in-app
   node_modules dir
3. to install node.js globally (and any desired module as well).

Basically, I use env.config to replace deploy&config hooks with customized ones (see below). Also, in a default EB container setup some env variables are missing (`$HOME` for example) and `node-gyp` sometimes fails during rebuild because of it (took me 2 hours of googling and reinstalling libxmljs to resolve this).

Below are the files to be included along with your build. You can inject them via env.config as inline code or via `source: URL` (as in this example)

**`env.vars`** (desired node version & arch are included here and in env.config, see below)

```
export HOME=/root
export NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
export NODE_VER=0.10.24
export ARCH=x86
export PATH="$PATH:/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v$NODE_VER-linux-$ARCH/bin/:/root/.npm"
```

**`40install_node.sh`** (fetch and ungzip desired node.js version, make global symlinks, update global npm version)

```
#!/bin/bash
#source env variables including node version
. /opt/elasticbeanstalk/env.vars

function error_exit
{
  eventHelper.py --msg "$1" --severity ERROR
  exit $2
}

#UNCOMMENT to update npm, otherwise will be updated on instance init or rebuild
#rm -f /opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/npm_updated

#download and extract desired node.js version
OUT=$( [ ! -d "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install" ] && mkdir /opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install ; cd /opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/ && wget -nc http://nodejs.org/dist/v$NODE_VER/node-v$NODE_VER-linux-$ARCH.tar.gz && tar --skip-old-files -xzpf node-v$NODE_VER-linux-$ARCH.tar.gz) || error_exit "Failed to UPDATE node version. $OUT" $?.
echo $OUT

#make sure node binaries can be found globally
if [ ! -L /usr/bin/node ]; then
  ln -s /opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v$NODE_VER-linux-$ARCH/bin/node /usr/bin/node
fi

if [ ! -L /usr/bin/npm ]; then
ln -s /opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v$NODE_VER-linux-$ARCH/bin/npm /usr/bin/npm
fi

if [ ! -f "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/npm_updated" ]; then
/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v$NODE_VER-linux-$ARCH/bin/ && /opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v$NODE_VER-linux-$ARCH/bin/npm update npm -g
touch /opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/npm_updated
echo "YAY! Updated global NPM version to `npm -v`"
else
  echo "Skipping NPM -g version update. To update, please uncomment 40install_node.sh:12"
fi
```

**`50npm.sh`** (creates /var/node_modules, symlinks it to app dir and runs npm install. You can install any module globally from here, they will land in /root/.npm)

```
#!/bin/bash
. /opt/elasticbeanstalk/env.vars
function error_exit
{
  eventHelper.py --msg "$1" --severity ERROR
  exit $2
}

#install not-installed yet app node_modules
if [ ! -d "/var/node_modules" ]; then
  mkdir /var/node_modules ;
fi
if [ -d /tmp/deployment/application ]; then
  ln -s /var/node_modules /tmp/deployment/application/
fi

OUT=$([ -d "/tmp/deployment/application" ] && cd /tmp/deployment/application && /opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v$NODE_VER-linux-$ARCH/bin/npm install 2>&1) || error_exit "Failed to run npm install.  $OUT" $?
echo $OUT
```

**`env.config`** (note node version here too, and to be safe, put desired node version in env config in AWS console as well. I'm not certain which of these settings will take precedence.)

```
packages:
  yum:
    git: []
    gcc: []
    make: []
    openssl-devel: []

option_settings:
  - option_name: NODE_ENV
    value: production
  - option_name: RDS_HOSTNAME
    value: fill_me_in
  - option_name: RDS_PASSWORD
    value: fill_me_in
  - option_name: RDS_USERNAME
    value: fill_me_in
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:nodejs
    option_name: NodeVersion
    value: 0.10.24

files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/env.vars" :
    mode: "000775"
    owner: root
    group: users
    source: https://dl.dropbox.com/....
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/configdeploy/pre/40install_node.sh" :
    mode: "000775"
    owner: root
    group: users
    source: https://raw.github.com/....
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/50npm.sh" :
    mode: "000775"
    owner: root
    group: users
    source: https://raw.github.com/....
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/configdeploy/pre/50npm.sh" :
    mode: "000666"
    owner: root
    group: users
    content: |
       #no need to run npm install during configdeploy
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/40install_node.sh" :
    mode: "000775"
    owner: root
    group: users
    source: https://raw.github.com/....
```

There you have it: on t1.micro instance deployment now takes 20-30 secs instead of 10-15 minutes! If you deploy 10 times a day, this tweak will save you 3 (three) weeks in a year.
Hope it helps and special thanks  to AWS EB staff for my lost weekend :)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write a detailed follow-up to your own question, incredibly helpful!

Comment: Thanks for the great writeup. Quick clarification ... when you say, "to avoid rebuilding existing node modules, including in-app node_modules dir", are you saying that you added your application node_modules to source control? Thanks!

Comment: I meant, these hooks will avoid unnecessary rebuilding of binaries (i.e. running node-gyp) within NPM modules, installed globally and locally (inside app dir). Updated modules versions still will be installed and rebuilt (if necessary), but if nothing has changed in package.json since last deployment, no extra actions will be taken by NPM and deploy will take less than a minute (on t1.micro instance).

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I missed your symlink, ln -s /var/node_modules /tmp/deployment/application/, thanks!

Comment: This is amazing! Just wondering how this will work with the autoscaling?

Comment: I have created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/etiennea/9861792) so we can improve this. I have added --production to npm install since no need to install testing frameworks on the server. Also added export NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true which does the same. Did not know which method was better

Comment: nice addition! I kinda open-sourced my hooks, as they're getting more sophisticated and I needed public  repo to keep the up-to-date files available for any elastic beanstalk instance. Feel free to fork or participate:
https://github.com/kopurando/better-faster-elastic-beanstalk

Forking my hooks for your own purposes is a good idea as I keep adding stuff that is probably needed only for my own project.

Comment: recent additions:
- update nginx binaries (i.e. custom built nginx of any version/modules configuration)
- added PhantomJS 
- tweak nginx configs
- improved logging (it's more realtime now, so log.io can be a good measure of deployment process)

Comment: as for scaling, I'm about to test it this week, will keep this topic and BFEB updated.

Comment: Hi Kirill. Thanks for these amazing notes! How did the auto scaling work?

Comment: We haven't had a chance to test in autoscaling environment yet, as it turned out that larger instances spread across regions currently suit our use-case better. Personally, I can't envision any problems with configs described, especially if you consider using leader_only option to avoid command clashes on multiple instances, for example:
`  04_setup_crontab:`
`    command: crontab /tmp/cronjob && rm /tmp/cronjob`
`    leader_only: true`
Moreover, I'm pretty sure you can check on the instance whether it's a leader or not and conditionally run (or don't run) specific hooks or scripts.

Comment: I believe symlinking doesn't works anymore in node.js v6. Removing them I could `npm install` okay.

Comment: Also, current EB requires a supported NodeVersion.

Comment: if you have time, would you mind creating a pull request in https://github.com/kopurando/better-faster-elastic-beanstalk? As I have been out of development for more than a year now, and do not follow latest EB trends..

Answer (score 5):

There's npm package that's overwriting default EB behaviour for `npm install` command by truncating following files:

- /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/50npm.sh
- /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/configdeploy/pre/50npm.sh

https://www.npmjs.com/package/eb-disable-npm

Might be better than just copying script from SO, since this package is maintained and probably will be updated when EB behaviour will change.

Answer (score 2):

I've found a quick solution to this. I looked through the build scripts that Amazon are using and they only run `npm install` if package.json is present. So after your initial deploy you can change it to `_package.json` and `npm install` won't run anymore! It's not the best solution but it's a quick fix if you need one!

Comment: but how will you get modules installed or updated w/o package.json?

Comment: I'm just using it for a small project at the moment with a small number of dependencies, so I'm uploading the `node_modules`. However if you're not adding node modules often you could leave `package.json` there for  the initial deploy and then change it. That way they're installed but rebuild is never run.

Otherwise this quick (and hopefully temporary) solution isn't for you!

Answer (score -7):

I had 10+ minute builds when I would deploy. The solution was much simpler than others have came up with... Just check node_modules into git! See http://www.futurealoof.com/posts/nodemodules-in-git.html for the reasoning

Comment: Elastic Beanstalk seems to be calling rebuild with NPM.  I don't know if this is a recent change, but for compiled stuff this wouldn't really help as far as I can tell.

Comment: This won't work for compiled libraries - example: zmq. If you build on mac, it won't deploy to linux. Just something to keep in mind.

Comment: My `node_modules` for a basic webpack+react+koa app is 500MB. Pass. However, the pain I have felt from remote dep management might justify it.

Comment: The link has died. This seems to work well for us. Our solution in detail was to 1) include modules we don't want to be run through "npm install" in .gitignore, 2) move those modules in packages.json to devDependencies section, 3) run npm install without --production flag on the deployment machine, 4) deploy to EB