# Deploy Angular 2 App to EC2

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, angular, amazon-ec2, backend

I hope this is the correct place to be asking this question, please move or delete this post if it's not.

I am trying to create a simple website that can handle basic POST and GET requests using Angular 2 and Amazon EC2. I have a fair amount of experience with working on the front end of a web app in Angular 2, but little experience with connecting that to a back end and doing so on an Amazon EC2 instance.

I was hoping to find an example or some resources that would explain how to use the HTTP service with a backend framework of some kind. I know that Angular provides examples of how to use the HTTP service, but its hard to picture what the backend setup needs to look like to handle these requests and also how to correctly configure this setup on EC2. Any help or resources would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can host your website in AWS S3. The backend will be sit in EC2. then you need in your specify the backend base url in your angular2 project (I mean all the calls will be to the backend server) and this url should be the url for your EC2. In addition your backend should accept request from the S3 server (in order to avoid CORS issues)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Frontend/client**

As @glavan said, SPA like angular 2 apps can be deployed in AWS S3. This is the most cost efficient approach for SPAs. Here is a video deploying [SPA on S3](https://egghead.io/lessons/misc-hosting-a-static-website-on-amazon-s3).
This video will guide you through step by step instructions for deploying your angular app.

**Backend**

AWS EC2 is a good option. But there are many more alternatives available. As you said, you were new to backend, setting up EC2, VPC's and Elastic-ip is a little difficult process.

Nowadays, SPA's cover a lot of business logic, routing, etc., We need our **backend** only as API's for performing CRUD operations with database. I would like to suggest a bleeding edge technology called [serverless](https://serverless.com/). Here is the [tutorial](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/blob/master/docs/01-guide/README.md) for launching your backend within 5 minutes. AWS lambda is a service that is called as **function as service**. You can build your backend using **AWS lambda + API gateway + DynamoDB**.

**For eg**: say you want to register some details in backend, you will **POST** all the data from client to your backend with url and proper path. In AWS lambda, you write your logic for **POST** as a function, which contains the logic to parse the data from request and send to dynamoDB. Now, this function can be exposed to world by connecting this function with API gateway( an another service in AWS). At the end we get an API, which can be used in your angular 2 APP. SO, on invoking the POST, **angular 2 -> API gateway -> Lambda(extract request and send to DB) -> dynamoDB**.

Benefits of using serverless compared to EC2.

1. You don't need to manage your server(EC2) from updating the new security patch to auto-scaling, everything is taken care by lambda. Serverless is a fully managed service.
2. You only pay when your lambda functions are invoked. On the contrast, even though your web app doesn't receive traffic for a given day, you have to pay the day-tariff for the given day.

Having said, try serverless when compared to traditional backend approach. Any questions on this would be welcomed.

Comment: Thank you for all of the help! In the end, I ended up using a modified version of this starter https://github.com/ansrivas/angular2-flask but I will mark this as accepted because it addresses all of the questions I had.

Comment: may be check out this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39783099/deploying-react-redux-app-in-aws-s3/39783111#39783111

Answer (score 3):

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43555413/5224768)

If you are referring to elastic beanstalk nodejs ec2, then this answer is best for you, as it took me a while to figure this out, but it turns out to be easier than I thought:

1. Following [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23242623/5224768) with some modifications I did to avoid `/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory` issues, I added the following script

**`.ebextensions/angular2deployment.config`**

```
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/env.vars" :
    mode: "000775"
    owner: root
    group: users
    content: |
      export NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
      export NODE_PATH=`ls -td /opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-* | head -1`/bin
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/50npm.sh" :
    mode: "000775"
    owner: root
    group: users
    content: |
      #!/bin/bash
      . /opt/elasticbeanstalk/env.vars
      function error_exit
      {
        eventHelper.py --msg "$1" --severity ERROR
        exit $2
      }

      #install not-installed yet app node_modules
      if [ ! -d "/var/node_modules" ]; then
        mkdir /var/node_modules ;
      fi
      if [ -d /tmp/deployment/application ]; then
        ln -s /var/node_modules /tmp/deployment/application/
      fi

      OUT=$([ -d "/tmp/deployment/application" ] && cd /tmp/deployment/application && $NODE_PATH/node $NODE_PATH/npm install 2>&1) || error_exit "Failed to run npm install.  $OUT" $?
      echo $OUT
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/configdeploy/pre/50npm.sh" :
    mode: "000666"
    owner: root
    group: users
    content: |
       #no need to run npm install during configdeploy
```

2. Delete `node_modules` & `dist` folder if you have, both are not needed.
3. Run `npm install && npm start` (this step must be successful), note that I'm using the angular2's default `package.json` [See Angular.IO Deployment](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/deployment.html)
4. If #3 is successful, then you can re-delete `node_modules` again
5. Select All files & folders in the project (make sure `.ebextensions` is selected as well), and then compress them, do not compress the top folder (you will have subdirectory when deploying which will break the deployment)
6. Now you can deploy that compressed file and enjoy!

If you are using MacOS, while compressing, macos will add macos folder which will break the deployment, make sure using a tool that won't add this extra directory, in my case I used `YemuZip`

Additional note: EC2 elastic beanstalk will run `npm install` & `npm start`, this is why I would recommend running them and make sure that they are fine on your local environment