# same domain name for lambda function api endpoints(backend) and for frontend

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, serverless-framework

How to use same domain name for front end and for lambda function endpoints
for Serverless framework ?

I am using reactjs for frontend design and for frontend hosting I am using s3 and Aws Dynamodb for lambda functions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deploying react-redux app in AWS S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39783099/deploying-react-redux-app-in-aws-s3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do the same in our systems, AWS solved it long time back.

It is the cloud service called CloudFront, which lets you connect multiple origins including external origins that are outside of AWS cloud.

Created a simple architecture diagram to help you view the same.

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for reply !! Is there any other option other than cloudFront

Comment: There are 100 thousand ways to solve this problem. This is the best I could think of in AWS.

Comment: I have configured cloud front as you ( @Kannaiyan ) mention above and my website working fine but I am getting {"message":"Missing Authentication Token"} for apis

Comment: That is outside the scope of this question. Check it out on other forums. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=192977